# What's the best way to navigate to a page dynamically in PHP?

Tags: php

For example, I have a form. Depending on the answers of the form, I want to take them to a different page on my site after submission. Here this is how I would think to do this assuming the action attribute of the form is submitted.php:

In submitted.php, do what the script needs to do based on the answers of the form, and then direct them by setting the header in php.

I'm asking this question because I hear a lot of people say you shouldn't bounce people around using headers.

So what way is best, if not my solution, and what is the argument against using header('location:');?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. 

Okay, so now that this is settled, would my $_POST variables come with it or would I have to put them into a session variable or something like that?

Comment: Same thing here, use if(isset($_POST['...'])) to check if a variable exists before accessing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending a Location header is exactly what you should do. There is nothing wrong in doing the following:

```
header('Location: http://www.site.com/?answer=' . rawurlencode($_POST['answer']));
```

*Except for input validation, but that is subject of another discussion.*

Comment: If you `rawurlencode()` the parameter you don't have to care about input validation either.

Comment: What if you only want to allow redirection to a specified number of urls?

Comment: What if one of the allowed values contain `&` or some other char with special meaning in a URL?

Comment: I agree that you should urlencode the parameter. I'm just saying that we don't know all the requirements so it's a different discussion.

Comment: We agree on the point I was arguing so I've edited your answer and upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any arguments against using `header()`-redirects in PHP. Just make sure you don't exaggerate and redirect from a redirect to another redirect…